# Wordpress Ordering (boolean?)

Tags: php, wordpress, boolean

Hi I would like to order custom fields in wordpress. I've got it displaying the single project. But can't figure out how I can get it to display in order. I've created a field called project_order which works correctly on another page.

But i'm not used to this sort of php with order by. This is a project designed by someone else so i'm trying to pick up and learn how it was built.

```
<?php
//associate sector to product projects page
$sector['construction'] = 131;
$sector['timber-frame'] = 235;
$sector['industrial'] = 253;
$sector['agriculture'] = 263;

//link to view all projects for product
echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink($sector[$post->post_name]).'" class="bigbutt">View all projects</a></p>';
?>
</div>

<div class="span5">
<div id="latestproject">
<h2>Latest Project</h2>
<?php
//get latest projects
$rows = get_field('projects', $sector [$post->post_name] , '&order=ASC');


//display latest project
if ($rows) {

    echo '<div class="row">';

    if ($rows[0]['project_pageturner']) {
        echo '<a href="'.$rows[0]['project_pageturner'].'" target="_blank">';
    } else if ($rows[0]['project_pdf']) {
        echo '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($rows[0]['project_pdf']).'" target="_blank">';
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:alert('No PDF uploaded for this item.')\">";
    }
    echo '<div class="span2">';
        if ($rows[0]['project_thumbnail']) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($rows[0]['project_thumbnail'], 'full');
        } else {
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/defaultproject.jpg" alt="">';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="span3">';
    echo '<p><strong>'.$rows[0]['project_title'].'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p>View project &raquo;</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';

    echo '</div><!--row-->';

} else {
    echo '<p>No projects to display currently.</p>';
}
?>
```

I'm guessing it will have something to do with.

```
$rows = get_field('projects', $sector [$post->post_name]);
```

Comment: Figured it out 

<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $project[$key]  = $row['project_order'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($project, SORT_ASC, $rows);
?>

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, may be this resolve your problem.

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();
//associate sector to product projects page
$sector['construction'] = 131;
$sector['timber-frame'] = 235;
$sector['industrial'] = 253;
$sector['agriculture'] = 263;

//link to view all projects for product
echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink($sector[$post->post_name]).'" class="bigbutt">View all projects</a></p>';
?>
</div>

<div class="span5">
<div id="latestproject">
<h2>Latest Project</h2>
<?php
//get latest projects
$rows = get_field('projects', $sector [$post->post_name] , '&order=ASC');


//display latest project
if ($rows) {

    echo '<div class="row">';

    if ($rows[0]['project_pageturner']) {
        echo '<a href="'.$rows[0]['project_pageturner'].'" target="_blank">';
    } else if ($rows[0]['project_pdf']) {
        echo '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($rows[0]['project_pdf']).'" target="_blank">';
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:alert('No PDF uploaded for this item.')\">";
    }
    echo '<div class="span2">';
        if ($rows[0]['project_thumbnail']) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($rows[0]['project_thumbnail'], 'full');
        } else {
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/defaultproject.jpg" alt="">';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="span3">';
    echo '<p><strong>'.$rows[0]['project_title'].'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p>View project &raquo;</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';

    echo '</div><!--row-->';

} else {
    echo '<p>No projects to display currently.</p>';
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks.